# answered with some mystification

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I’d like to ask about the sentence from The Retired Colourman by Conan Doyle.

> "Quite so," I answered with some mystification. "And on B row."

Could anyone elaborate how Dr. Watson was like when he said something with some mystification. Did he seem to be proud because he remembered such details? Or was he a bit puzzled because what  Holmes asked was too-obvious? 
Thank you.

Comment: You need to supply more context for Watson's reply if you expect an answer. However, being a Sherlock Holmes fan I checked out the story. I believe Watson was mystified as to why Holmes should think the seat number on the theatre ticket important.

Comment: He was mystified when he said it, so it was said with mystification.